# Volume of Tee Tube

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

Looking for a smart way to calculate the volume of a tee tube below by any means necessary, advanced calculus if need be.

[image: Image of a tee tube]

Comment: See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html)

Comment: Thank you, never heard the name before and could not google it either!